android notification icon is not visible on android 13 or greater but works on android 12
I am using audio_service to control audio from notification bar. There is a list of controls that takes MediaControl, MediaControl has a property named androidIcon that takes a string. I have added all the necessary icons to the drawable folder and the icons are visible on android 12 devices but is not visible in android 13+. Though the icon that comes with library works fine.
this is code that I wrote and on the side these are the drawables
I have tried multiple android 13+ devices to test it but still there is no solution to it.

Please don't post code in screenshots. Just paste the text unto your question and format it as code.
